# validating google form before "submit"

Tags: validation, google-apps-script, google-forms

I'm looking for a way to validate a form "before" submitting it.
I need to:

a) get total value of field A : from linked Response Sheet. If total value > 0 then proceed to step b. If not, then "deactivate" field A and proceed to step c.
b) FORM'S field A can receive input.
c) if not, choose another field (B, C...or F)
... and so on.

Can this be done, without having to SUBMIT (which will close it) and being sent to the RESPONSE SHEEET? I want to stay in the FORM until final approval of input by user and validation scripts.

[my wip form](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSdtRCT9E0rAiweDArtQfc0WHvxmAEBQaS0ggnH3GwdEpn4ovw/viewform?fbzx=8899072100942106000)

Below some literature I am reading at the moment.

```
// Open a form by ID and log the responses to each question.
 var form = FormApp.openById('1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz');
 var formResponses = form.getResponses();
 for (var i = 0; i < formResponses.length; i++) {
   var formResponse = formResponses[i];
   var itemResponses = formResponse.getItemResponses();
   for (var j = 0; j < itemResponses.length; j++) {
     var itemResponse = itemResponses[j];
     Logger.log('Response #%s to the question "%s" was "%s"',
         (i + 1).toString(),
         itemResponse.getItem().getTitle(),
         itemResponse.getResponse());
   }
 }
```

[google developers's forms reference:](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-response)

Comment: Once the user hits the Submit button in a Google Form, it is not possible to prevent the answers from being saved into the Google Form.  If that's what you are asking.  There is "built-in" validation capability for individual questions, but you can't do something like change the options in another question based on how the first question is answered.  You can show other pages or not, depending upon how a question is answered.  But, if users need to edit their previous response, there have been problems with the original data not getting saved if the user doesn't re-visit every question.

Comment: txs @SandyGood. So, the 2 alternative I'm left with are:

1) evaluate each question, and according to their "state" I could change their colour to RED as a warning to the user no to use them ,
2) to validate the after-submit data in my Response Sheet and, if data are not as expected, to send back to the user an editable form link to modify his answers. Along with that email, I could send him a list of suggested options still available.

Comment: You can certainly do any type of evaluation that you want *after* the submission and then send an email back with any information that you want, and an Edit URL to edit the original submission.

Answer (score 1):

Google Forms include a built-in way to validate some questions types. We could programmatically add validations to supported question types by using  [Class TextValidationBuilder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/text-validation-builder) but we can't use JavaScript to make validations before the response is submitted.

After the response is submitted we could use JavaScript to make validations but the results of them will not be shown on the form response view.